# One client: static IP vs Static lease DHCP vs. DHCP limited range to 1 slot

Tags: router, ipv4, networking

I want to attach one client (only 1 maximum) to network router ethernet port. I want to always know the client's IP address, for my port forwarding settings. Using DHCP with range the client IP could be anything in the range, depending on old leases -> unsuccessful port forwarding.

I have 3 options

1. Use static IP address for the interface
2. Use DHCP, with MAC address static lease
3. Use DHCP, but with only 1 slot available (e.g. range 192.168.10.100-192.168.10.100)

Are these options equivalent? Why not?
For option 2 I can see that using the MAC address lease requires more custom configuration than the options 1 and 3 would.

Comment: Static configuration does not scale, but if you are doing this for only one host, then it probably is not worth setting up a scope on your DHCP server just for one device. You really have not described the network or network device models, and how the DHCP server is connected to the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## DHCP w/ static assignment

This is probably the best option because the DHCP configuration, small as it is, documents the address usage.  It also allows you to use DHCP options to configure any additional properties on the host, if required.

## Static IP configuration on the host

This is a reasonable choice as well; but even in small SOHO environments, it can become more difficult to manage if you add hosts in the future.

## Single address dynamic IP pool

A one-address dynamic IP pool might be problematic if another device is ever connected, the MAC address of the host changes (new NIC card?) or similar.  I don't recommend this configuration.

Comment: Thank you for thorough answer. I might use the static IP option to avoid setting up static leases based on MAC address.
This is embedded setup with only 1 host and 1 client. Namely, single IP camera setup to router with 4G connection. I will create N number of these router+camera setups, and thus the setup time is meaningful to me.

Answer (score 0):

To optimise network performance  assign static ip address to client .if you choose this option . No need to configure DHCP configuration in router so that router performance will be high unnecessary router resources are not utilized for DHCP process to work . Moreover network bandwidth can be optimised by avoiding unnecessary DHCP DORA process packets exchanges between DHCP server and client..

Answer (score -1):

They are equivalent in the sense that you will get the same result.  Arguing which is easier to implement or more flexible is a matter of opinion, which is off topic here.